# Sort output of Get-Migrations ascending?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, powershell, entity-framework-6

By default, the [Get-Migrations](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Get-Migrations) command, when run in the Visual Studio Package Manager Console, returns the list of Entity Framework migrations that have been applied to the target database in descending order. That is, the list is sorted to have most recent migrations first.

**Is there a way to make Get-Migrations return the list of migrations in ascending order, that is, oldest migrations first, instead?**

What I've tried so far:

- Piped the output to the [Sort-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176968.aspx) cmdlet, e.g. `Get-Migrations [my params] | Sort-Object -Property Name` (I'm not sure what property name to specify, or if this is even applicable?). All of these attempts silently failed (no error message displayed, no change in the Get-Migrations output).
- Looked at the Powershell help for Get-Migrations (`Get-Help Get-Migrations`) and searched the web to see if Get-Migrations itself has a parameter that controls the output sort order.  Couldn't find one.

Output of the Get-Migrations command I'm currently getting:

```
PM> Get-Migrations [my arguments...]
Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.
201704121534436_SomeMigration999
201703291334212_SomeMigration998
[lots and lots more records here that are a pain to scroll through...]
201410110448547_InitializeTables
201410110018266_InitialCreate
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide some sample of the unsorted output you are getting?

Comment: @sodawillow Good question, done!

Comment: Is this `cmdlet` provided by Microsoft?

Comment: @sodawillow Yes. Although I'm not 100% of the exact source within Microsoft, I suspect it's provided as part of Entity Framework: http://msdn.com/data/ef

Comment: If you can include steps to reproduce, I'd be happy to try. But I guess you need some (sample) project/database. I have Visual Studio 2017 RC (I can install 2015 if needed).

Comment: @sodawillow There are a lot of moving parts to set up to be able to repro, so I won't ask you to try -- this question was more of a convenience / "should be easy" kind of thing, anyway, nothing mission-critical. I do very much appreciate all of your help anyway! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided sample output it seems the command returns text.

I'd `split` on the linebreaks, and the on the `_` to get the 2 properties separated, be able to sort things afterwards:

```
#$migrations = Get-Migrations "..."

#test values
$migrations = "201704121534436_SomeMigration999
201703291334212_SomeMigration998
201410110448547_InitializeTables
201410110018266_InitialCreate"

$migrations.Split("`n") | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Date = $_.Split("_")[0]
        Name = $_.Split("_")[1]
    }
} | Sort-Object Name
```

Comment: I like this idea! However, since I'm in Package Manager Console, I think I need to do this as a one-liner.  For starters, I tried the following, but am getting a "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error: (Get-Migrations [params]).Split("`n")

Comment: The output of Get-Migrations prints before the error occurs. I wonder if the Get-Migrations cmdlet prints its output as it is running, instead of returning the output as a string.  I might be out of luck?

Comment: If the output of the command cannot be "captured" I don't know how to proceed. Maybe there is a parameter to specify an output file?